# Execute setTimeout inside for loop after specific time intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, timer

I want to loop through some numbers i.e. for each iteration loop should execute after specific time period like, 1st iteration should execute on the 1st second, next should execute after 2 seconds and so on...

I am using the [flapper plugin](http://www.jaykayess.com/flapper/) to display the numbers. Following is my snippet.

```js
var $lucky = $('.lucky');
$lucky.flapper({
  width: 1,
  chars_preset: 'alpha',
  align: 'right',
  timing: 1000,
  min_timing: 100,
  threshhold: 100,
  animation: 'slow',
  //transform: true,
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var numbers = ['G', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
  var length = numbers.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    console.log(numbers[i]);
    var $lucky = $('#lucky' + [i]);
    setTimeout(function() {
      var $lucky = $('#lucky' + [i]);
      var num = numbers[i];
      $lucky.val(num).change();
    }, 500);
    console.log(i);
  }
});
```

```css
.header {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky0" />
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky1" />
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky2" />
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky3" />
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky4" />
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky5" />
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky6" />
</div>
```

Comment: setTimeout with different timeout values

Comment: @Tommy how to do that , please much help needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your `setTimeout` into a [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). This is because `setTimeout` runs asynchronously. The moment it is about to execute after specified time i.e. 500 ms, the loop would be finished by that time.

Here is a modification to your code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var numbers = ['G', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
    var length = numbers.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        (function(i){
            console.log(numbers[i]);
            var $lucky = $('#lucky' + [i]);
            setTimeout(function() {
                var $lucky = $('#lucky' + [i]);
                var num = numbers[i];
                $lucky.val(num).change();
            }, (1000 * i));
        })(i);
    }
});
```

Wrapping the timeout in that IIFE will capture the value of `i` in each iteration.

```
(function(i){
    // loop will execute whatever inside 
    // with a new value of i in each iteration....
})(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the loop and use `setInterval()` to have the loop effect.

```js
var $lucky = $('.lucky');
$lucky.flapper({
  width: 1,
  chars_preset: 'alpha',
  align: 'right',
  timing: 1000,
  min_timing: 100,
  threshhold: 100,
  animation: 'slow',
  //transform: true,
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var numbers = ['G', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
  var i = 0;
  var length = numbers.length;
  var inteval = setInterval(function() {
    var num = numbers[i];
    $('#lucky' + i).val(num).change();
    if (++i >= length)
      clearInterval(inteval);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.header {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://www.jaykayess.com/flapper/css/flapper.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jaykayess.com/flapper/src/jquery.flapper.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky0" />
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky1" />
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky2" />
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky3" />
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky4" />
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky5" />
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky6" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the value 500 in `setTimeout` with a variable. `setTimeout` counts time in milliseconds so you need to multiply the numer (2,3,4, e.t.c) with 1000 to get the time in seconds

```
var timeout = 0;
if(numbers[i] != 'G'){
    timeout = numbers[i] * 1000;
}
else{
    //set timeout for 'G'
}
setTimeout(function() {
  var $lucky = $('#lucky' + [i]);
  var num = numbers[i];
  $lucky.val(num).change();
}, timeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function yourFunction() {
    console.log('Hello');
}

timeIntervals = [1000,2000,3000,4000,5000];
$.each(timeIntervals,function(k,startAfter) {
setTimeout(yourFunction, startAfter);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and have it call itself after a timeout. On each iteration the array index is incremented by 1 until it is equal to the array's length.

```js
$(function() {
  
  var numbers = ['G', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
      length = numbers.length,
      index = -1,
      interval = 500;
    
  (function next(){
      index++;
      if(index<length){
         console.log(numbers[index]);
         $('#lucky' + index).val(numbers[index]).change();
         setTimeout(next,interval);
      }
  })();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky0" />
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky1" />
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky2" />
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky3" />
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky4" />
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky5" />
  <input class="header light XXL lucky" id="lucky6" />
</div>
```